# Horizontal split hotkey not working in ConEmu

Tags: terminal, hotkeys, conemu

I've setup the vertical split hotkey to "Alt+Shift+H" in ConEmu (see screenshot below). However when I press this hotkey it's openining a new terminal in a new tab instead of splitting the current one.

I actually got it working at some point but after making somes changes to the config, it appears to be broken. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've restricted ConEmu from running more than a one console in a window.

[Settings / Appearance](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsAppearance.html#id1506)